# Counting/word-wraping of CJK characters

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, CJK characters (Chinese, Japanese, Korean) are considered as double characters, both in the Column count (shown in the status bar) and in the word wrap (when "editor.wordWrapColumn" is used). For example, when I type 全, VS Code considers that I've typed 2 characters instead of 1. Although this may be *visually* true, I would prefer a *non-visual* counting/word-wraping, where CJK characters are considered as single characters (i.e. equal to Latin letters). Is there a way to customize the behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac computer, I ended up going to the folder:

```
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs
```

and replacing all occurrences of:

```
return(e=+e)>=11904&&e<=55215||e>=63744&&e<=64255||e>=65281&&e<=65374
```

with:

```
return!1
```

**Explanation:** The original code is from a function called "isFullWidthCharacter", which checks whether a caracter is CJK or not. After my proposed replacement, it always says not.